# close the application while a button is clicked in android

Tags: android, button

I want to close the application and force close when i click this button.  Here is the code that I've tried so far.  But the application doesn't close.  How can I make the app close when the button is pushed?

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  setOnCompletionListener{
        private static final String TAG = null;

        int [] songs;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        int current_index = 0; 
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    songs= new int[] {R.raw.song2,R.raw.song3,R.raw.song7};

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[0]);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        mediaPlayer.start();



Button btnstop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); //Play
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View vone) 
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this your main activity

Comment: I am having mediaplayer playing in the background .when i click the stop button .I want to stop the songs as well as close the application.

Comment: IT IS giving and error on the main setOnCompletionListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: That has to do with the code about the mediaPlayer, show that code.

Comment: change `implements setOnCompletionListener` to `implements OnCompletionListener` in your class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btnstop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); //Play
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View vone) 
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release ();

        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: it is an error in the main "setOnCompletionListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: i edited the code .Please help me.setOnCompletionListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: just remove implements  setOnCompletionListener and mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); for now

Comment: thank you .it is working now.But why i have to remove setOnCompletionListener ?.

Comment: If you want to do something after the media player finishes playing the song for example playing another set of song then you need to setOnCompletionListener. As @Karakuri pointed out you get the wrong thing after implements.

Comment: it stops after the first song.it is not moving to the next song.

Comment: So you need to implement the OnCompletionListener to play the next song. Put back implements OnCompletionListener and mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); to the place before

Comment: The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.onCompletion(MediaPlayer) MainActivity.java /ListProject/src/com/bama/example/listproject line 15 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

To call finish method, you should extend Activity in your class, because finish() method is inside Activity class...

Also you could try to pass activity to your class as a parameter and call activity.finish(). Although i am not sure if this works...

```
class foo(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

//inside onclick
activity.finish();
```